# Serial: Could not obtain serial port with an NI PCI 8431/16 interface

Tags: drivers, pcie

I have a problem with obtaining serial port with NI PCIe instrument card. I am running Ubuntu 20.04

Initially I tried to discover my serial port configuration with

```
sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS*
```

It shows a list of serial port but with only /dev/ttyS0 showing an uart : 16550A, something like below

```
/dev/ttyS0, uart: 16550A, port :0x03f8, irq: 4
/dev/ttyS1, uart: unknown, port: 0x02f8, irq:3
/dev/ttyS2, uart: unknown, port: 0x03e8, irq:4
/dev/ttyS3, uart: unknown, port: 0x02e8, irq:3
.....
```

The rest doesn't even have port and irq being assigned. I believe that /dev/ttyS0 is assigned as a "generic" port and is not the port provided by the NI card.

Next I tried to query the pci information

```
sudo lspci -vvv > pci.txt
```

And found that the memory region for the card being disabled

```
.....
Region 0: memory at d8e00000(32bit, non prefectable) [disabled][size 4k]
....
```

I tried to use setpoint to enable it again

sudo setpci -s [device_id]:[memory_addr] COMMAND=0x02

Checking with lspci again, the word [disabled] is being removed. And then checking with setserial commands again, there is nothing change

**Driver Reinstallation**

Tried reinstalling the drivers ni-ubuntu2004-drivers-2023Q3.deb but seem nothing change

**How to proceed**

Wonder what else can I try? Is it a case of irq conflict or?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does `id` show you're in the same group (probably `serial`) as `ls -l /dev/tty*`?

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l /dev/ttyS0`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/ttyS0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: your solution does not seem to deal with the problem i am facing...but anyway thanks